# What is the exact meaning of はな in the sentence: 「世の中的にはな。」

Tags: particle-は, parsing

In order to understand the meaning of this sentence:

> "まぁうん 一応 世の中的にはな。"

I put the complete conversation below:

> Son: 「大人」って何？「大人」ってどういうこと？
> Father: 大人？
> Son: うん 親父 大人だろ？
> Father: まぁうん 一応 世の中的に**はな**。
> Son: いや 真面目に聞いてんだけど。

Comment: 三浦春馬さんの「サムライハイスクール」ですよね

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84223/45489 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72490/45489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not はな{hana}, but はな{wana}. The は is actually the particle "wa" here.

The part `一応世の中的にはな` should be interpreted with the preceding context, which makes it `一応世の中的には親父は大人だろう`. The な at the end is a sentence-ending particle, just like よ or ね.

In casual speech, it's not a problem to put XXXは(the subject) at the end of the sentence, and in fact, since all parts of a sentence in Japanese are clearly labeled by particles, in daily speech one could alter the sentence order however they like, and we do that sometimes in English too.

> Take that book to you, I will. (I will take that book to you)
> あの本を上げるよ、俺は。 (俺はあの本を上げるよ)
> あの本を上げるよ、君に。（君にあの本を上げるよ）

So, for your conversation, you should interpret the sentences as such:

> 「大人」って 何? (What's an adult?)
>
> 「大人」って どういうこと?  (Adult is what kind of thing?)
>
> 大人? (Adult?)
>
> うん 親父 大人だろ?  (Yeah, my father should be an adult?)
>
> まぁうん 一応 世の中的にはな。 (Um, yes, at least in this world's standard)
> (一応 世の中的に**は**俺は大人だろう**な**)

Comment: セリフの切れ目がわかりにくかったようなので、質問の方には改行を入れましたが、以下のように切れます： Son:「大人って何？大人ってどういうこと？」"What is an adult? What does it mean to be an adult?" Father: 「大人？」 "Adult?" Son:「うん、親父、大人だろ？」"Yes, dad, you're an adult, right?" Father: 「まぁうん、一応、世の中的にはな。」"Well, yeah, I am, at least in public standard." Son: 「いや、真面目に聞いてんだけど。」"Hey, I'm asking you seriously."

Comment: あっごめん。二人の話なのか？一人の自白だと思ってたんでした。

Comment: Thank  you very much